# Sorted() not sorting properly

Tags: python, sorting

The code i'm working with has a list of lists that contains (moviename, year released, genre, watched or unwatched). I am trying to sort the list by year released to display, however it is not sorting properly

`movielist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`

This is the code i'm trying to run to sort a list of lists by year,  but it is not sorting properly.

Output is:

```
['Citizen Kane', '1941', 'Drama', 'u']
['Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope', '1977', 'Action', 'w']
['The Fugitive', '1993', 'Drama', 'u']
['Fun with Dick and Jane', '2005', 'Comedy', 'w']
['Persian-Roman War', '557', 'Action', 'u']
```

when it should be:

```
['Persian-Roman War', '557', 'Action', 'u']
['Citizen Kane', '1941', 'Drama', 'u']
['Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope', '1977', 'Action', 'w']
['The Fugitive', '1993', 'Drama', 'u']
['Fun with Dick and Jane', '2005', 'Comedy', 'w']
```

Comment: sorting properly it is, just not they way you would want it to; the reason for that is that the years are stored as text and not as numbers. You can adapt your `key` to remedy that (e.g., `movielist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))`).

Comment: `movielist.sort(key = lambda x:int(x[1]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are doing

```
movielist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

It sorts based on string values which does not work in your case

Use this instead

```
movielist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Hope this Helped

Comment: This is the same as Sayandip's comment, given two minutes before you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are sorting on a *text* year, and lexicographically, the year `1941` is "before" `557`.  You may try left padding the year with zeroes to a fixed width of 4:

```
movielist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].zfill(4))
```

With this approach, sorting on the text year works, and would give the following order:

```
0557
1941
1977
1993
2005
```

Comment: A padding solution assumes you know the max possible digit count of your population. So, what is the advantage over converting to some number representation?

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, on retrospect I should've probably known this.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Um...the second column is a year, not a population.  I doubt that OP's data would have a year greater than 9999.

Comment: @Ron_Pearlyman Apparently you could also just cast the second column to integer, e.g. sort on `int(x[1])`.

Comment: IMO converting the value to int should be preferred

Comment: @Tim "population" as in collection of whatever values you are using for the sorting. The padding approach is also hiding potential errors the OP might have in case of an year entry like `"N/A"` or something.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Well if you want to open that can of worms, then any row which has a string value which cannot be cast to integer would also fail for the solution you have in mind.  Stop reading edge cases which aren't really there.

Comment: @Tim when a user with 290k goes for a solution that is not the *typical* one, you have to wonder if there is some deeper knowledge that led them to take this non-standard path. That's what I am trying to figure out..